# Moq returning an object from a method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have the following unit test and I'm using MOQ to set-up an object returned from a class. However when I try to reference mock.Object it is referencing the interface type not the type that I'm trying to return

```
var throughFareIdentifer = new ThoroughfareNumberIdentifier();

var throughfareMock = new Mock<ILLUSiteInformation>();
 throughfareMock.Setup(x => x.GetThroughfareNumber("15")).Returns(throughFareIdentifer);


var siteInformation = _lluSiteInformation.GetSiteDetails("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", throughfareMock.Object);
```

throughfareMock.Object should be ThroughfareNumberIdentifier not IlluSiteInformation.

any help with this would be appreciated

thanks

Chris

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with you actual and expected behavior. This will be used to assist you with your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doing what you told it to do. By creating `new Mock<ILLUSiteInformation>();` you're saying "Give me a Mock of type `ILLUSiteInformation`".

When you use your setup:

```
throughfareMock.Setup(x => x.GetThroughfareNumber("15")).Returns(throughFareIdentifer);
```

You're saying "When `GetThroughfareNumber` is called, and passed the number 15 as a string, return `throughFareIdentifier`".

Call `throughfareMock.Object.GetThroughfareNumber()` instead of using the Mock Object, like so

```
_lluSiteInformation.GetSiteDetails("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", throughfareMock.Object.GetThroughfareNumber("15");
```

Make sure you only use the number 15 as a string (because that's what you set up). If you want to use any string, call

```
throughfareMock.Setup(x => x.GetThroughfareNumber(It.IsAny<string>)).Returns(throughFareIdentifer);
```

If you want to use an int

```
throughfareMock.Setup(x => x.GetThroughfareNumber(It.IsAny<int>)).Returns(throughFareIdentifer);
```

Comment: thanks. Do i event need to do the set-up if I use throughfareMock.Object.GetThroughfareNumber()? thanks

Comment: That's up to you. It depends on how you use the `throughfareMock` object and what you're planning on doing with it. Generally when I use Mocks, I pass `Mock.Object` into an object's constructor, taking an interface, where it will use the methods of the interface. Much like you have there. I generally don't call the Mocked object's methods in my test code. It's your call

Comment: thanks. Sorry Im slightly confused. I have used the throughfareMock.Object.GetThroughfareNumber("15") in the constructor now and thats working fine. As I have discovered in other examples why do the set-up to get the return type from a method. I want to try and avoid call the method inside of the method call. Thanks

Comment: I don't follow. There's no constructor there.... You're only using it in `GetSiteDetails`.

Comment: Here, join this chat so we're not polluting the question: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/119032/moq

Comment: instead of using throughfareMock.Object.GetThroughfareNumber("15") in the GetSiteDetails call. I'm trying to understand the point of the set-up in the example I used. If I'm asking to return throughfarenumberType  in the set-up how can I reference this without calling the method again in the GetSiteDetails call